# Casperjs and Meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor, casperjs

im trying to scrap a website and download a file and i found CasperJS as a good option and very mature.

I did a server method (under SERVER folder) and i call this code just to test it:

```
Meteor.methods({
  gpsDw: function() {
    var casper = Meteor.npmRequire('casper');
  }
});
```

and i get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'casper'
```

But if i execute casper on a single file `casperjs mysample.js` it runs perfect.

Comment: CasperJS can't be run inside of another framework like meteor/node, it can only be used independently.

Just like PhantomJS can only be executed as a 'stand-alone' framework

Comment: oh thanks i'v been asking that for a while @venturz909, is there any good scrapping library to be used inside ?

Comment: I haven't used meteor - with node.js you can use request and cheerio.  CasperJS is really great on its own though.